# How to set JButton size with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to set the size of my JButtons that are at the center of my screen to become larger but I can't seem to find how to do that using GridBagLayouts.

Here is how it looks like :
[image: This is what it looks like]

Here is my code :

```
    //      Client
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.gridy = 5;
    c.gridx = 5;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.insets = new Insets(10, 1, 1, 10);
    p.add(b[0], c);

    //      Server
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.gridy = 10;
    c.gridx = 5;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.insets = new Insets(10, 1, 1, 10);
    p.add(b[1], c);
```

I want the buttons to take up a larger portion of the empty space around them.

Comment: Are you sure the buttons are not covering a whole cell of the grid? You add them at position (5,5). And if you just want to play two buttons on top of each other FlowLayout, GridLayout, BorderLayout and BoxLayout are all more suitable.

Comment: I used 5,5 just to give allowance for if I ever need to add anything to the side, I don't have to change the grid coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information was added: Buttons have 50% of the width and [about] 20% of the height of parent [together 50% height including the space in between]. (Slightly rewritten to match the suggestion.)

**Solution**

Combination of simple Layouts Layouts. Although if you do it like this you will have 3 columns or 3 rows which can't be joined, the rest can easily be changed later:

```
// row variation

JPanel parent = new JPanel();
parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

parent.add(new JPanel()); // placeholder for 1st row

JPanel row = new JPanel(); // 2nd row
row.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3)); // create 3 cells of equal size

row.add(new JPanel()); // 2nd row, 1st cell placeholder

// now you have a 33% x 33% (oops) rectangle in the middle
JPanel controls = new JPanel();
controls.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 10, 10));
controls.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
controls.add(new JButton("Client"));
controls.add(new JButton("Server"));

row.add(controls); // add 2nd row, 2nd cell

row.add(new JPanel()); // 2nd row, 3rd cell placeholder

parent.add(row); // add 2nd row

parent.add(new JPanel()); // placeholder for 3rd row
```

Easy, but you won't be able to join the cells later:

JPanel parent = new JPanel();
   parent.setLayout(newGridLayout(9, 9));

**Bottom line: combine different layout managers, put your 2 buttons inside a panel and put some placeholders inside, then it should also work fine with GridBagLayout.** That said, I would try to stay flexible by writing **reusable components** which can easily be combined with any layout manager. Then you don't have to use placeholders superfluous code in order to display the components correctly.

**Old Answer**

Alternative Solution: Use BoxLayout

BoxLayout is more intuitive and easier to understand when looking at code (of course this is only an opinion).

1. Decide how your window is structered (is it more like big horizontal components on top of each other `PAGE_AXIS` or big vertical components next to each other `LINE_AXIS`) and use this as the outer BoxLayout:

   ```
   JPanel content = new JPanel(); // or frame
   content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
   ```
2. Add the components along the axis, where you have more than one component along the other axis use a 2nd BoxLayout. You can space components by creating rigid areas (empty rectangles always having the same size) or by adding glue (expanding like gum together with the components).

   ```
   content.add(BoxLayout.createHorizntalGlue());

   JPanel col = new JPanel();
   col.setLayout(new BoxLayout(col, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
   JButton clientBtn = new JButton("Client");
   JButton serverBtn = new JButton("Server");
   col.add(BoxLayout.createVerticalGlue());        
   col.add(clientBtn);
   col.add(BoxLayout.createRigidArea(new Dimension(1, 10)));
   col.add(serverBtn);
   col.add(BoxLayout.createVerticalGlue());
   content.add(col);

   content.add(BoxLayout.createHorizontalGlue());
   ```

Comment: you maybe want to use rigid areas everywhere instead of glue to get the desired behavior, I'm not sure what you want. But this layout is very flexible and can be extended any time.

Comment: I'm making that as sort of my main menu. I'll be repainting it later on with a different layout but I wanna know how to do this so I can implement it in the future. As for the size, the same percentage but changes when the window resizes. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: @JavaFanatic If you really want to make a sophisticated Layout, then GridBagLayout is not a bad choice, the spacing could probably be fixed by adding a few dummy panels, but if you also want to resize the font and border etc. then there is no way around handling resize events.

Comment: @JavaFanatic Math... it is wrong, this solution only gives 33% x 33% in the middle

Comment: Ok looking at all information, I think the best solution would be to use a BorderLayout (and put in CENTER, placeholders needed) or use a BoxLayout (with glue, no placeholders required) on the parent. Then put the buttons in a controls panel using GridLayout with gap and border so that there is space but the buttons will be stretched. But you will have to adjust preferredSize on of the controls panels if the parent is resized

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine what do you want, but if you want your button to fill around, you can add

```
    c.weightx = ...; //Specifies how to distribute extra horizontal space. 
    or c.weighty = ...; //Specifies how to distribute extra vertical space.
```

Comment: I tried that method and it ends up making my button expand too much filling all the space completely. I don't want that either.

Comment: only set manual:  yourButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));

Comment: it works now, thanks! Would it be possible though to set it to a size relative to the window size so that when the window is resized, so are the buttons?

Comment: @JavaFanatic that is the whole point of layout managers, did you only try 1.0? Use 0.9 as weight. And... but I wouldn't recommend it, you can also listen for resizing events and adjust.

Comment: @JavaFanatic: Add listen for resizing events and adjust to your size

Comment: @maraca I tried using 0.9 as weight as well as 0.1 and other numbers greater than 1.0 and they all still seemed to make my buttons swell up to fill almost the entire screen.

Comment: @JavaFanatic It will become ugly with listener, just combine 2 simple layout managers, it is so much easier, GridBagLayout is rarely needed, I think BoxLayout combined with others is much better to emulate the same.

Comment: @maraca I'll try though I'm not sure how it will turn out as my experience with LayoutManagers is limited to the GridBagLayout manager.

Comment: @JavaFanatic can help you if you specify what you need exactly, e.g. 2 buttons that take 50% of width and height and sit in the middle of parent?

Comment: @maraca Width is 50% while height is 20% per button and sit in the middle.

Comment: @JavaFanatic Do you only want that or do you want to be able to add other components later and the size of the buttons should not change? And you can ask under my answer we don't need to disturb Thanh Le

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setMargin( new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50) );
```

This will add extra space to the button and allow the layout managers to do their job based on the preferred size of the button.